# Split series on time gaps and on distance from the first element of the group in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with keys and timestamps.

| Key | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12.00 |
| A | 12.30 |
| A | 13.00 |
| A | 14.00 |
| B | 12.00 |
| B | 13.30 |

I want to create groups of rows such that, given a key:

- If a row's timestamp comes more than 30 minutes after the last row timestamp, the row belongs to a new group
- If a row's timestamp comes more than 1 hour after the timestamp of the first row in the group, the row belongs to a new group.

| Key | Timestamp | Group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12.00 | 0 |
| A | 12.30 | 0 |
| A | 13.00 | 0 |
| A | 13.30 | 1 |
| B | 12.00 | 2 |
| B | 13.30 | 3 |

The result should be in GroupID column.

Separately I can apply those conditions after having sorted the dataframe by timestamp.
For the first:

```
df.groupby('key)['timestamp'].diff()>thirty_minutes)
```

For the second one:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1h')
```

However I have no idea how to put these two conditions together and obtain the column Group_id.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the to timestamps, you can count the number of minutes `seconds / (seconds per minute * minutes in half hour)` between each row using `diff`.  Any row with a diff > 1 is farther apart than 30 minutes.

Worth noting that index 4 actually goes back in time from the previous row, and thus has a negative diff.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
 'Timestamp': ['12.00', '12.30', '13.00', '14.00', '12.00', '13.30']})

df['Group_id'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%H.%M')
      .diff()
      .dt
      .seconds
      .div((60*30))
      .gt(1)
      .cumsum()
)
```

EDIT

If looks like you want to also consider new Keys to be a new group, which I missed in the original answer.  You could check if the gap > 1 or if the previous Key is different as such:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
     'Timestamp': ['12.00', '12.30', '13.00', '14.00', '12.00', '13.30']})

df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%H.%M')
df['gap'] = df.groupby('Key').ts.diff().dt.seconds.div((60*30)).gt(1)
df['Group_id'] =(df['Key'].ne(df['Key'].shift(fill_value=df.Key.iloc[0])) | df['gap']).cumsum()
df[['Key','Timestamp','Group_id']]
```

Output

```
  Key Timestamp  Group_id
0   A     12.00         0
1   A     12.30         0
2   A     13.00         0
3   A     14.00         1
4   B     12.00         2
5   B     13.30         3
```